# going through a string of characters and extracting the numbers?

Tags: c++, c, string, extract

Given a string of characters, how can I go through it and assign all the numbers within that string into an integer variable, leaving out all other characters?

I want to do this task when there is a string of characters already read in through `gets()`, not when the input is read.

Comment: You may read about Why `gets()` is bad": http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351. - Also, what would "12xyz34" result in: 12 or 1234?

Comment: Be careful - that will only work if the digits in your input string, when combined, don't overflow the int type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int get_num(const char* s) {
  unsigned int value = 0;
  for (; *s; ++s) {
    if (isdigit(*s)) {
      value *= 10;
      value += (*s - '0');
   }
  }
  return value;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Here is a safer version of the function.
It returns 0 if `s` is `NULL` or cannot be converted to a numeric value at all. It return `UINT_MAX` if the string represents a value larger than `UINT_MAX`.

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int safe_get_num(const char* s) {
  unsigned int limit = UINT_MAX / 10;
  unsigned int value = 0;
  if (!s) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (; *s; ++s) {
    if (value < limit) {
      if (isdigit(*s)) {
        value *= 10;
        value += (*s - '0');
      }
    }
    else {
      return UINT_MAX;
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: That is neat but...what if the value maxes out the maximum number for the type unsigned int?

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple C++ way to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;   

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    istringstream is("string with 123 embedded 10 12 13 ints", istringstream::in);
    int a;

    while (1) {
        is >> a;
        while ( !is.eof() && (is.bad() || is.fail()) ) {
            is.clear();
            is.ignore(1);
            is >> a;
        }
        if (is.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Extracted int: " << a << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [`strtol` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) from the standard C library. It allows you to find the part of a character array that is a number, and points to the first character that isn't a number and stopped the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/): it works like `scanf` but on a string (char array).

`sscanf` might be overkill for what you want though, so you can also do this:

```
int getNum(char s[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; s[i]; ++i )
        if ( s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9' )
            ret = ret * 10 + (s[i] - '0');

    return ret;
}
```